# Getting Timer class to change the state of a boolean and remove a GIF from the application yet website freezes

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have a gif that I run whenever someone creates a new book. When the submit button is clicked, the checked `bool` becomes `true` and, in turn, an `if` statement that checks for this boolean runs and showcases the image.

However, I want to remove this gif after 3 seconds of displaying it. I tried using the StopWatch class but that didn't work when I tried it (someone on SO mentioned that you need a `Timer` for Blazor apps) so I resorted to using `Timer`.

The problem, given this context, is the app simply stops running. Here's the code

```
@using blazorTestApp.Client.Entities
@using System.Timers
@code
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public Books CreatedBook {get; set;} = new Books();
    bool check = false;
    public void OnSubmit()
    {
        check = true;
    }
}

@if(check)
{
    <img class="Thanks" src="https://gifsec.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/thank-you-gif-1.gif"/>
    timer.Interval = 3000;
    timer.Start();
    timer.Elapsed += (Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) => check = false; StateHasChanged(); timer.Stop();  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build out a timer, you can use the inbuilt Task timer for one time delays.  Here's a demo page that displays an alert box for three seconds instead of your image.  It shows two ways to set up the delay.  For simple short waits use the simpler.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@if(_loading)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">Thanks for your business</div>
}

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@_loading" @onclick=OnLoad>Load Image</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" disabled="@_loading" @onclick=OnLoadAsync>Load Image</button>
</div>


@code {
    private bool _loading;

    // This way is simpler but means the task is "owned" by the Renderer
    // and the UI task doesn't complete until the delay is complete
    private async Task OnLoadAsync()
    {
        _loading = true;
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        _loading = false;
    }

    private Task _showTask = Task.CompletedTask;

    // This way hands off the wait to a task so the Ui task completes immediately 
    // and the Task is owned by the component
    private Task OnLoad()
    {
        // assign the load task to _showTask but don't await it.
        _showTask = LoadTaskAsync(3000);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task LoadTaskAsync(int millisecs)
    {
        _loading = true;
        StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Delay(millisecs);
        _loading = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that worked! I simply used the await Task.Delay() since it didn't seem to interfere with other functionalities. But could you elaborate please on how the second method you have works? As in how does it effect _loading if it doesn't change its state

Comment: The second method kicks off a task that runs in the background.  It sets `_loading` and calls `StateHasChanged` which queues a UI Update.  The await yields control back to the UI which services the render queue and update the UI.  Once the Delay completes, the task resets `_loading` and queues another UI update.  The task completes yielding control back to the UI which services the render queue and renders the component.